# C# closures behavior changes if a instantiate the object before versus inside the lambda?

Tags: c#, lambda, closures, parameter-passing

So I found this weirdness where the behavior of my code changes depending on where I allocate the object that will be "closured" in my lambda function.

Here's a simplified example of what I was experiencing

```
Example01(){
    var myCounterLocalInstance = new MyCounter(); 
    Action<string> lambdaFunction = (args) => IncrementAndPrint(args, myCounterLocalInstance);
}

Example02(){
   Action<string> lambdaFunction = (args) => IncrementAndPrint(args, new MyCounter());
}

IncrementAndPrint(string args, MyCounter counter){
   Console.WriteLine(args + counter.GetValueAndCount());
}

class MyCounter
{
   int _counter;
   public int GetValueAndCount() => _counter++;
}
```

The weirdness is that Example01 and Example02 don't actually give the same results in my case. in Example01, everything works as expected, and the console output would be, if args == "cat":

1. log: "cat0"
2. log: "cat1"
3. log: "cat2"

This is expected behavior, as MyCounter is stateful.
Example02, however, would give the following outputs:

1. log: "cat0"
2. log: "cat0"
3. log: "cat0"

The _counter member variable is reset everytime the method is called... It's like myCounter is passed by value and is being reinstantiated every time it is used in Example02, instead of being put into a closure object like in the first example -- like was expected.

Is there some explanation for this? I'm guessing this is known behavior and not a bug? There must be something about closures I don't know about. It caused me a ton of headache as I never thought behavior could change depending on where I allocate the arguments of a closure.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is incomplete, where is the action called? `lambdaFunction = (args) => IncrementAndPrint(args, new MyCounter());` so each call creates a new instance. I'm not sure why you find that surprising....

Comment: My real concern is why you think they should be the same. Every time you call `lambdaFunction` you have either a single instance in (`Example01`), or creating a new instance (`Example02`)... Can see why you would get different results even if you just called this method statically?  `IncrementAndPrint("cat", myCounterLocalInstance)` or  `IncrementAndPrint("cat", new MyCounter());`

Comment: `new MyCounter()` gets called on each invocation. It gets a new one every time.

Comment: hmm ok that make's sense. I just thought that when you create a lambda, it would initially store all it's dependencies as members in an object, and then just pass those to whatever method you put in. But yeah of course it isn't just storing members and a function, it's CREATING an entirely NEW function. I guess I just forgot that it could do that, in the context of me using them to sort of just overload a method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are over-thinking this.

In this method, you are creating one instance of `MyCounter`, that increments every time you invoke the delegate.

```
static void Example01(){
   var myCounterLocalInstance = new MyCounter(); 
   Action<string> lambdaFunction = (args) => IncrementAndPrint(args, myCounterLocalInstance);
   lambdaFunction("cat");
   lambdaFunction("cat");
   lambdaFunction("cat");
   lambdaFunction("cat");
}
```

In this method you are creating a new instance `MyCounter` every time you invoke the delegate, its count will always be 0!

```
static void Example02(){
   Action<string> lambdaFunction = (args) => IncrementAndPrint(args, new MyCounter());
   lambdaFunction("cat");
   lambdaFunction("cat");
   lambdaFunction("cat");
   lambdaFunction("cat");
}
```

You would get the same results if you just called the `IncrementAndPrint` statically:

```
static void Example01(){
   var myCounterLocalInstance = new MyCounter();
   IncrementAndPrint("cat",myCounterLocalInstance);
   IncrementAndPrint("cat",myCounterLocalInstance);
   IncrementAndPrint("cat",myCounterLocalInstance);
   IncrementAndPrint("cat",myCounterLocalInstance);
}

static void Example02(){
   IncrementAndPrint("cat", new MyCounter());
   IncrementAndPrint("cat", new MyCounter());
   IncrementAndPrint("cat", new MyCounter());
   IncrementAndPrint("cat", new MyCounter());
}
```